Switching from X11 to Wayland in KDE: finding alternatives for xset, xgamma, and other command-line tools
I am trying to switch from X11 to Wayland in KDE (Fedora 40). Several of commands I used do not work anymore, like xset, xgamma, etc. Of course, I tried to look for alternatives/workarounds, and failed miserably: the very few indications that I found simply did not work for me.
For example:

How do I get the monitor/display information, if it is on/off? In X11 I use
xset -q | grep -qi "monitor is off"

(I asked this 3 months ago for Plasma 6.0 here, without luck... is there any way?)

How do I change the gamma from the command line? In X11 I use e.g.
xgamma -display :0 -quiet -rgamma 1.00 -ggamma 0.85 -bgamma 0.7




The problem with finding X11 equivalents on Wayland is that for each
feature it takes a long time for a standard protocol to be decided upon, so
that it can be provided in the compositor, and used by applications. During
that time, each desktop and so on develops their own ad hoc implementation,
and since the world has decided that a gui is more important than the cli,
you end up with graphical settings that are often not documented adequately
in a searchable way.
(For your first point, I've provided an answer in the linked-to post.)
For gamma on KDE, you can read about the ongoing development effort for HDR and colour
management in May 2023,and an update in December 2023.
The first suggests you can use
colord to manage ICC
profiles for applications that uses it.
You can also search for user-provided applets on pling.com, for example
search for gamma,
and you find things such as Redshift control for Plasma 6 and XrendrMixer. I'm not a KDE user so I don't know if these are relevant.

I see. I don't want to use ICC profiles, I always calibrate my monitor using online resources and got more correct RGB gamma values for each of my monitors. Anyway, if I have to do all this kind of partial workarounds for each single X11 command that stopped working (after a decade since Wayland appeared!), I will stay with X11. Thanks for the info!
